# identifying a number that is stored in the contacts during an incoming or outgoing call

Tags: java, android

There's a class that iextends BroadcastReceiver.I have the action "isNumberStored (Context context, String number)" which returns "true" if a phone number (string of numbers) exists in the contacts.
When a incoming or outgoing call starts I want to **get the phone number** and than **check if the number is stored in my contacts** or not. How can I apply this?

my class :

```
public class CallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    // ^ detecting incoming and outgoing calls ^
    public void onReceive(Context context , Intent intent) {
     
        if (intent.getStringExtra( TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE ).equals( TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK )) {
          //Call started

        } else if (intent.getStringExtra( TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE ).equals( TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE )) {
           //Call ended

        } else if (intent.getStringExtra( TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE ).equals( TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING )) {
             //Incoming call
            }
    }


    //Check if number is stored in Contacts list  (Truth = exists).

    public boolean isNumberStored(Context context, String number) {
        Uri lookupUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(
                ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI,
                Uri.encode(number));
        String[] mPhoneNumberProjection = { ContactsContract.PhoneLookup._ID, ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.NUMBER, ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME };
        Cursor cur = context.getContentResolver().query(lookupUri,mPhoneNumberProjection, null, null, null);
        try {
            if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
                cur.close();
                return true;
            }
        } finally {
            if (cur != null)
                cur.close();
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are just asking how to make a Toast message, then the answer is this:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"I am a message",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

if not, I would like you to edit the question to be more focused on what you are asking. does this help you?

Comment: I meant how can I get the phone number of an incoming or outgoing call. And then check if the number is stored in my contacts. (The toast message is not the problem). Thanks for your reply anyway.